# Extending Indonesian tourist stay on a visa exempt

Tags: visas, indonesia, visa-free-entry

Is there a way to extend the Indonesian tourists stamp (visa exempt) which is valid for 30 days without leaving the country? I am a citizen of a visa exempt country. A few months ago I used to get the VOA (a sticker) and I know I can extend that, but now that's not applicable for me since Indonesia made the exempt list so long and now it includes my country. So, is there a way to extend this stay as we used to do with the VOAs or not?

Note that the stamp says "Not extendable".

So, is there a way?

[image]

Comment: I'm confused: are you visa-exempt or do you require a visa on arrival? Visa-free stays cannot be Extended, whereas visas on arrival can be Extended once for another 30 days.

Comment: @Crazydre my bad, fixed the question... the transition from VOA to visa exempt was done not long ago so I myself got confused.

Comment: When it says 'non extendable' I expect it to be that. Better try to get a long term multiple entry visa or a residence visa if you qualify. I would not risk overstaying, due to possible trouble with getting visa or 'no visa needed' stamps.

Comment: @Willeke  true.. a sudden event made me decide that so I asked in case there's a way... there is always a way.. I guess I will have to do a visa run..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visa-free stays cannot be extended, so if you want to stay longer legally you have to exit the country.

I don't really know their policy on visa runs - some countries are fine with it while others aren't.

Comment: Why the downvote? +1 from me..

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis Hmm, I see. My sources at Indonesian Immigration say there is no such restriction, so good to know